# SAS proc freq or proc sql to obtain frequency of a subset of data and whole data

Tags: sql, sas, frequency, sas-macro

I am trying to obtain frequency based on two different datasets (with their subsets). Consider the following example

```
DATA Group1;
INPUT Subject_ID education;
DATALINES;
1 LowerPrimary
2 Secondary
3 UpperPrimary
4 LowerPrimary
5 Secondary
6 Secondary
7 LowerPrimary
8 UpperPrimary
9 UpperPrimary
10 Secondary
;
RUN;
```

```
DATA Group2;
INPUT Subject_ID education;
DATALINES;
1 LowerPrimary
2 Secondary
3 UpperPrimary
4 LowerPrimary
5 Secondary
6 Secondary
7 LowerPrimary
8 UpperPrimary
9 UpperPrimary
10 Secondary
11 LowerPrimary
12 UpperPrimary
;
RUN;
```

I would like to a code to obtain the following output in SAS.

```
         Lower_Primary Upper_Primary Primary_Total Secondary Group_Total
Group1      3               3            6           4          10
Group2      4               4            8           4          12
```

`Primary_Total=Lower_Primary+Upper_Primary` while
`Group_Total=Lower_Primary+Upper_Primary+Secondary`

Comment: Is your desired result a SAS data set or a report? How many data sets are input here?

Comment: The desired result is a report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example of where using a MULTILABEL format can help.

First combine the data into one dataset with a GROUP variable so you can process it all at once.  (Note your posted dataset steps cannot work as you defined EDUCATION as numeric.)

```
data Group1;
  input Subject_ID education $20.;
datalines;
1 LowerPrimary
2 Secondary
3 UpperPrimary
4 LowerPrimary
5 Secondary
6 Secondary
7 LowerPrimary
8 UpperPrimary
9 UpperPrimary
10 Secondary
;
data Group2;
  input Subject_ID education $20.;
datalines;
1 LowerPrimary
2 Secondary
3 UpperPrimary
4 LowerPrimary
5 Secondary
6 Secondary
7 LowerPrimary
8 UpperPrimary
9 UpperPrimary
10 Secondary
11 LowerPrimary
12 UpperPrimary
;

data both;
  set group1(in=in1) group2(in=in2);
  if in1 then group='GROUP1';
  else group='GROUP2';
run;
```

Then define a multilabel format that generates the categories you want.

```
proc format ;
value $education (multilabel notsorted)
  'LowerPrimary' = 'LowerPrimary'
  'UpperPrimary' = 'UpperPrimary'
  'LowerPrimary','UpperPrimary' = 'Primary'
  'Secondary' = 'Secondary'
  'LowerPrimary','UpperPrimary','Secondary' = 'Group_Total'
;
run;
```

Now we can use a procedure that supports multilabel formats, such as PROC TABULATE, to generate your report.

```
proc tabulate data=both order=data ;
  class group;
  class education / mlf preloadfmt;
  format education $education.;
  table group,education;
run;
```

Results

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                          |                           education                            |
|                          |----------------------------------------------------------------|
|                          |LowerPrimary|UpperPrimary|  Primary   | Secondary  |Group_Total |
|                          |------------+------------+------------+------------+------------|
|                          |     N      |     N      |     N      |     N      |     N      |
|--------------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------|
|group                     |            |            |            |            |            |
|--------------------------|            |            |            |            |            |
|GROUP1                    |        3.00|        3.00|        6.00|        4.00|       10.00|
|--------------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------|
|GROUP2                    |        4.00|        4.00|        8.00|        4.00|       12.00|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```